# Additional space added while reading text from Notepad using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

My requirement is to find the location of a particular string in a line from notepad file but while reading it in powershell additional space get added that's why not able to find the location of a particular string. How I can find the location is this case??

I am using this code for achieving this

```
$ParamsPathForData = ($dir + "\TimeStats\TimeStats_1slot\29_12_2015_07TimeStats1.txt")

$data = Get-Content $ParamsPathForData
write-host $data.count total lines read from file
foreach ($line in $data)
{
 $l =$line.IndexOf("12/29/2015")
       write-host $l    
  }
```

I am reading this line from notepad ->

> TimeStats 29  12/29/2015 7:13:42 AM +00:00    Debug   PREPROCESS: SlotNo:
>   325-00313, Ip Address: 10.2.200.15, Duplicate Message: False,
>   Player-Card-No: , MessageId: 883250003130047966, MessageName:
>   GameIdInfo, Thread Init Delay: 14, Time To Parse: 155, Time To Exec
>   Main Workflow: 424, Time To Construct & send Response: 22, Total
>   Response Time: 615

But while exceuting it in  powershell i am getting this with additinal spaces ->

> T i m e S t a t s      2 9     1 2 / 2 9 / 2 0 1 5   7 : 1 3 : 4 2   A M
>   + 0 0 : 0 0    D e b u g   P R E P R O C E S S :   S l o t N o :    3 2 5 - 0 0 3 1 3 ,   I p   A d d r e s s :   1 0 . 2 . 2 0 0 . 1 5 ,   D
>   u p l i c a t e   M e s s a g e :   F a l s e ,   P l a y e r 
>   - C a r d - N o :   ,   M e s s a g e I d :   8 8 3 2 5 0 0 0 3 1 3 0 0 4 7 9 6 6 ,   M e s s a g e N a m e :   G a m e I d I n f o ,    T h
>   r e a d   I n i t   D e l a y :   1 4 ,   T i m e   T o   P a r s e : 
>   1 5 5 ,   T i m e   T o   E x e c   M a i n   W o r k f l o  w :   4 2
>   4 ,   T i m e   T o   C o n s t r u c t   &   s e n d   R e s p o n s
>   e :   2 2 ,   T o t a l   R e s p o n s e   T i m e :    6 1 5

Anybody please help me???

Comment: No encoding. just using above mentioned code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the the encoding to Unicode...

`$data = Get-Content $ParamsPathForData -Encoding Unicode`

Comment: Was it ascii encoding instead of unicode that made this work for you? Just curious!